# Cannot construct ARRAY instance, invalid connection error in Oracle Retail Integration Bus (RIB) in Warehouse Management Database(WMS)

Tags: oracle

In our Oracle Retail Application in WMS messages are failing with the "Cannot construct ARRAY instance, invalid connection" error in Oracle Retail Integration Bus (RIB).
we are using RIB Version 12.0, I checked there is no network issue, between RMS and WMS, done a traceroute test as well, all connections are fine there.

Error Description :

```
com.retek.rib.translate.ObjectCreationException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot construct ARRAY instance, invalid connection
```

Due to this messages are getting stuck in rib_messages and topics are also getting stuck, I have to restart JMS and eways to flow the messages, and at the end of the day RIB Restart is a must, But I need a permanent solution to resolve this issue, every day this error is coming and restarting RIB every day is not recommended.
Didn't find any solution in oracle community portal .

So, any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching, finding solutions everywhere we found that, rib sessions were killed by DBA, and that caused this issue.

RIB is restarted after every week, so rib sessions will be shown as inactive sessions but killing those sessions must be avoided.

After avoiding this, never faced this issue again.